# Error while deploying python code into azure throgh VS code

Tags: deployment

I am trying to deploy a python code from VSC and I get the following error:

7:11:44 PM BabaOpenAi: Starting deployment...
7:11:44 PM BabaOpenAi: Creating zip package...
7:11:44 PM BabaOpenAi: Adding 11 files to zip package...
7:11:44 PM BabaOpenAi: c:\Users\viv_k\OneDrive\Documents\AzureFunction\requirements.txt
7:11:44 PM BabaOpenAi: c:\Users\viv_k\OneDrive\Documents\AzureFunction\host.json
7:11:44 PM BabaOpenAi: c:\Users\viv_k\OneDrive\Documents\AzureFunction\BabaOpenAI_*init*_.py
7:11:44 PM BabaOpenAi: c:\Users\viv_k\OneDrive\Documents\AzureFunction\CompletionAPI_*pycache*__*init*_.cpython-39.pyc
7:11:44 PM BabaOpenAi: c:\Users\viv_k\OneDrive\Documents\AzureFunction\BabaOpenAI\sample.dat
7:11:44 PM BabaOpenAi: c:\Users\viv_k\OneDrive\Documents\AzureFunction\BabaOpenAI\function.json
7:11:44 PM BabaOpenAi: c:\Users\viv_k\OneDrive\Documents\AzureFunction\CompletionAPI_*init*_.py
7:11:44 PM BabaOpenAi: c:\Users\viv_k\OneDrive\Documents\AzureFunction\CompletionAPI\sample.dat
7:11:44 PM BabaOpenAi: c:\Users\viv_k\OneDrive\Documents\AzureFunction\CompletionAPI\function.json
7:11:44 PM BabaOpenAi: c:\Users\viv_k\OneDrive\Documents\AzureFunction.funcignore
7:11:44 PM BabaOpenAi: c:\Users\viv_k\OneDrive\Documents\AzureFunction\BabaOpenAI_*pycache*__*init*_.cpython-39.pyc
7:11:44 PM BabaOpenAi: Zip package size: 4.42 kB
7:11:57 PM BabaOpenAi: Updating submodules.
7:11:58 PM BabaOpenAi: Preparing deployment for commit id 'd9ff4f7a-b'.
7:11:58 PM BabaOpenAi: PreDeployment: context.CleanOutputPath False
7:11:58 PM BabaOpenAi: PreDeployment: context.OutputPath /home/site/wwwroot
7:11:58 PM BabaOpenAi: Repository path is /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
7:11:58 PM BabaOpenAi: Running oryx build...
7:11:58 PM BabaOpenAi: Command: oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.9.7 -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages
7:12:00 PM BabaOpenAi: Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
7:12:00 PM BabaOpenAi: You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues
7:12:00 PM BabaOpenAi: Oryx Version: 0.2.20210120.1, Commit: 66c7820d7df527aaffabd2563a49ad57930999c9, ReleaseTagName: 20210120.1
7:12:00 PM BabaOpenAi: Build Operation ID: |us/YNb9iHgs=.742e6dea_
7:12:00 PM BabaOpenAi: Repository Commit : d9ff4f7a-b5ff-4b8b-bd06-b4690c8396b0
7:12:00 PM BabaOpenAi: Detecting platforms...
7:12:01 PM BabaOpenAi: Detected following platforms:
7:12:01 PM BabaOpenAi:   python: 3.9.7
7:12:01 PM BabaOpenAi: Version '3.9.7' of platform 'python' is not installed. Generating script to install it...
7:12:01 PM BabaOpenAi: Source directory     : /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
7:12:01 PM BabaOpenAi: Destination directory: /home/site/wwwroot
7:12:01 PM BabaOpenAi: Downloading and extracting 'python' version '3.9.7' to '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.7'...
7:12:02 PM BabaOpenAi: Downloaded in 1 sec(s).
7:12:02 PM BabaOpenAi: Verifying checksum...
7:12:03 PM BabaOpenAi: Extracting contents...
7:12:05 PM BabaOpenAi: Done in 4 sec(s).
7:12:05 PM BabaOpenAi: Python Version: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.7/bin/python3.9
7:12:05 PM BabaOpenAi: Running pip install...
7:12:06 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:06+0000] Collecting azure-functions
7:12:06 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:06+0000]   Downloading azure_functions-1.18.0-py3-none-any.whl (173 kB)
7:12:06 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:06+0000] Collecting openai
7:12:06 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:06+0000]   Downloading openai-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (226 kB)
7:12:07 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:07+0000] Collecting pydantic<3,>=1.9.0
7:12:07 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:07+0000]   Downloading pydantic-2.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (395 kB)
7:12:07 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:07+0000] Collecting httpx<1,>=0.23.0
7:12:07 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:07+0000]   Downloading httpx-0.27.0-py3-none-any.whl (75 kB)
7:12:07 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:07+0000] Collecting sniffio
7:12:07 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:07+0000]   Downloading sniffio-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
7:12:07 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:07+0000] Collecting typing-extensions<5,>=4.7
7:12:07 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:07+0000]   Downloading typing_extensions-4.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
7:12:07 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:07+0000] Collecting anyio<5,>=3.5.0
7:12:07 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:07+0000]   Downloading anyio-4.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (85 kB)
7:12:07 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:07+0000] Collecting distro<2,>=1.7.0
7:12:07 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:07+0000]   Downloading distro-1.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
7:12:08 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:08+0000] Collecting tqdm>4
7:12:08 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:08+0000]   Downloading tqdm-4.66.2-py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
7:12:08 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:08+0000] Collecting annotated-types>=0.4.0
7:12:08 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:08+0000]   Downloading annotated_types-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
7:12:11 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:11+0000] Collecting pydantic-core==2.16.3
7:12:11 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:11+0000]   Downloading pydantic_core-2.16.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (2.2 MB)
7:12:11 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:11+0000] Collecting idna
7:12:11 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:11+0000]   Downloading idna-3.6-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
7:12:11 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:11+0000] Collecting certifi
7:12:11 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:11+0000]   Downloading certifi-2024.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (163 kB)
7:12:12 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:12+0000] Collecting httpcore==1.*
7:12:12 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:12+0000]   Downloading httpcore-1.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
7:12:12 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:12+0000] Collecting exceptiongroup>=1.0.2; python_version < "3.11"
7:12:12 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:12+0000]   Downloading exceptiongroup-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
7:12:12 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:12+0000] Collecting h11<0.15,>=0.13
7:12:12 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:12+0000]   Downloading h11-0.14.0-py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
7:12:12 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:12+0000] Installing collected packages: azure-functions, annotated-types, typing-extensions, pydantic-core, pydantic, sniffio, idna, exceptiongroup, anyio, certifi, h11, httpcore, httpx, distro, tqdm, openai
7:12:14 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:42:14+0000] Successfully installed annotated-types-0.6.0 anyio-4.3.0 azure-functions-1.18.0 certifi-2024.2.2 distro-1.9.0 exceptiongroup-1.2.0 h11-0.14.0 httpcore-1.0.4 httpx-0.27.0 idna-3.6 openai-1.12.0 pydantic-2.6.3 pydantic-core-2.16.3 sniffio-1.3.1 tqdm-4.66.2 typing-extensions-4.10.0
7:12:14 PM BabaOpenAi: WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 24.0 is available.
7:12:14 PM BabaOpenAi: You should consider upgrading via the '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.7/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
7:12:14 PM BabaOpenAi: Done in 9 sec(s).
7:12:14 PM BabaOpenAi: Preparing output...
7:12:14 PM BabaOpenAi: Copying files to destination directory '/home/site/wwwroot'...
7:12:14 PM BabaOpenAi: Done in 0 sec(s).
7:12:14 PM BabaOpenAi: Removing existing manifest file
7:12:14 PM BabaOpenAi: Creating a manifest file...
7:12:14 PM BabaOpenAi: Manifest file created.
7:12:14 PM BabaOpenAi: Done in 13 sec(s).
7:12:15 PM BabaOpenAi: Running post deployment command(s)...
7:12:15 PM BabaOpenAi: Generating summary of Oryx build
7:12:15 PM BabaOpenAi: Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
7:12:15 PM BabaOpenAi: The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
7:12:15 PM BabaOpenAi: Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
7:12:16 PM BabaOpenAi: Linux Consumption plan has a 1.5 GB memory limit on a remote build container.
7:12:16 PM BabaOpenAi: To check our service limit, please visit https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#service-limits
7:12:16 PM BabaOpenAi: Writing the artifacts to a squashfs file
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi: Parallel mksquashfs: Using 1 processor
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi: Creating 4.0 filesystem on /home/site/artifacts/functionappartifact.squashfs, block size 131072.
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi: [=============================================================/] 1212/1212 100%
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi: Exportable Squashfs 4.0 filesystem, gzip compressed, data block size 131072
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi:  compressed data, compressed metadata, compressed fragments, compressed xattrs
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi:  duplicates are removed
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi: Filesystem size 4665.23 Kbytes (4.56 Mbytes)
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi:  31.68% of uncompressed filesystem size (14726.98 Kbytes)
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi: Inode table size 12473 bytes (12.18 Kbytes)
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi:  28.73% of uncompressed inode table size (43416 bytes)
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi: Directory table size 12301 bytes (12.01 Kbytes)
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi:  33.59% of uncompressed directory table size (36625 bytes)
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi: Number of duplicate files found 56
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi: Number of inodes 1350
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi: Number of files 1192
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi: Number of fragments 75
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi: Number of symbolic links  0
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi: Number of device nodes 0
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi: Number of fifo nodes 0
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi: Number of socket nodes 0
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi: Number of directories 158
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi: Number of ids (unique uids + gids) 1
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi: Number of uids 1
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi:  root (0)
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi: Number of gids 1
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi:  root (0)
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi: Creating placeholder blob for linux consumption function app...
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi: Malformed SCM_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE when uploading built content.
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi: Generating summary of Oryx build
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi: Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi: The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
7:12:18 PM BabaOpenAi: Deployment Failed. deployer = ms-azuretools-vscode deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
7:12:32 PM BabaOpenAi: Deployment failed.
7:18:33 PM BabaOpenAi: Starting deployment...
7:18:33 PM BabaOpenAi: Creating zip package...
7:18:33 PM BabaOpenAi: Adding 11 files to zip package...
7:18:33 PM BabaOpenAi: c:\Users\viv_k\OneDrive\Documents\AzureFunction.funcignore
7:18:33 PM BabaOpenAi: c:\Users\viv_k\OneDrive\Documents\AzureFunction\requirements.txt
7:18:33 PM BabaOpenAi: c:\Users\viv_k\OneDrive\Documents\AzureFunction\host.json
7:18:33 PM BabaOpenAi: c:\Users\viv_k\OneDrive\Documents\AzureFunction\BabaOpenAI_*init*_.py
7:18:33 PM BabaOpenAi: c:\Users\viv_k\OneDrive\Documents\AzureFunction\BabaOpenAI\sample.dat
7:18:33 PM BabaOpenAi: c:\Users\viv_k\OneDrive\Documents\AzureFunction\BabaOpenAI\function.json
7:18:33 PM BabaOpenAi: c:\Users\viv_k\OneDrive\Documents\AzureFunction\BabaOpenAI_*pycache*__*init*_.cpython-39.pyc
7:18:33 PM BabaOpenAi: c:\Users\viv_k\OneDrive\Documents\AzureFunction\CompletionAPI_*pycache*__*init*_.cpython-39.pyc
7:18:33 PM BabaOpenAi: c:\Users\viv_k\OneDrive\Documents\AzureFunction\CompletionAPI_*init*_.py
7:18:33 PM BabaOpenAi: c:\Users\viv_k\OneDrive\Documents\AzureFunction\CompletionAPI\sample.dat
7:18:33 PM BabaOpenAi: c:\Users\viv_k\OneDrive\Documents\AzureFunction\CompletionAPI\function.json
7:18:33 PM BabaOpenAi: Zip package size: 4.42 kB
7:18:41 PM BabaOpenAi: Fetching changes.
7:18:42 PM BabaOpenAi: Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/98e05af7-c51a-4e0b-8f3e-6d1aa4f56fee.zip (0.00 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
7:18:44 PM BabaOpenAi: Updating submodules.
7:18:45 PM BabaOpenAi: Preparing deployment for commit id '5b0c60e7-a'.
7:18:45 PM BabaOpenAi: PreDeployment: context.CleanOutputPath False
7:18:45 PM BabaOpenAi: PreDeployment: context.OutputPath /home/site/wwwroot
7:18:45 PM BabaOpenAi: Repository path is /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
7:18:45 PM BabaOpenAi: Running oryx build...
7:18:45 PM BabaOpenAi: Command: oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.9.7 -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages
7:18:46 PM BabaOpenAi: Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
7:18:46 PM BabaOpenAi: You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues
7:18:46 PM BabaOpenAi: Oryx Version: 0.2.20210120.1, Commit: 66c7820d7df527aaffabd2563a49ad57930999c9, ReleaseTagName: 20210120.1
7:18:46 PM BabaOpenAi: Build Operation ID: |AjxTSWrOIS0=.a0a9cf17_
7:18:46 PM BabaOpenAi: Repository Commit : 5b0c60e7-a965-4861-b513-63ae947921d6
7:18:46 PM BabaOpenAi: Detecting platforms...
7:18:47 PM BabaOpenAi: Detected following platforms:
7:18:47 PM BabaOpenAi:   python: 3.9.7
7:18:47 PM BabaOpenAi: Version '3.9.7' of platform 'python' is not installed. Generating script to install it...
7:18:47 PM BabaOpenAi: Source directory     : /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
7:18:47 PM BabaOpenAi: Destination directory: /home/site/wwwroot
7:18:47 PM BabaOpenAi: Downloading and extracting 'python' version '3.9.7' to '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.7'...
7:18:48 PM BabaOpenAi: Downloaded in 1 sec(s).
7:18:48 PM BabaOpenAi: Verifying checksum...
7:18:48 PM BabaOpenAi: Extracting contents...
7:18:51 PM BabaOpenAi: Done in 4 sec(s).
7:18:51 PM BabaOpenAi: Python Version: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.7/bin/python3.9
7:18:51 PM BabaOpenAi: Running pip install...
7:18:52 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:52+0000] Collecting azure-functions
7:18:52 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:52+0000]   Downloading azure_functions-1.18.0-py3-none-any.whl (173 kB)
7:18:52 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:52+0000] Collecting openai
7:18:52 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:52+0000]   Downloading openai-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (226 kB)
7:18:52 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:52+0000] Collecting httpx<1,>=0.23.0
7:18:52 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:52+0000]   Downloading httpx-0.27.0-py3-none-any.whl (75 kB)
7:18:52 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:52+0000] Collecting distro<2,>=1.7.0
7:18:52 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:52+0000]   Downloading distro-1.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
7:18:52 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:52+0000] Collecting anyio<5,>=3.5.0
7:18:52 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:52+0000]   Downloading anyio-4.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (85 kB)
7:18:53 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:53+0000] Collecting tqdm>4
7:18:53 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:53+0000]   Downloading tqdm-4.66.2-py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
7:18:53 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:53+0000] Collecting pydantic<3,>=1.9.0
7:18:53 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:53+0000]   Downloading pydantic-2.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (395 kB)
7:18:54 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:54+0000] Collecting typing-extensions<5,>=4.7
7:18:54 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:54+0000]   Downloading typing_extensions-4.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
7:18:54 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:54+0000] Collecting sniffio
7:18:54 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:54+0000]   Downloading sniffio-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
7:18:54 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:54+0000] Collecting httpcore==1.*
7:18:54 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:54+0000]   Downloading httpcore-1.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
7:18:54 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:54+0000] Collecting idna
7:18:54 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:54+0000]   Downloading idna-3.6-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
7:18:54 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:54+0000] Collecting certifi
7:18:54 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:54+0000]   Downloading certifi-2024.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (163 kB)
7:18:54 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:54+0000] Collecting exceptiongroup>=1.0.2; python_version < "3.11"
7:18:54 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:54+0000]   Downloading exceptiongroup-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
7:18:57 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:57+0000] Collecting pydantic-core==2.16.3
7:18:57 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:57+0000]   Downloading pydantic_core-2.16.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (2.2 MB)
7:18:57 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:57+0000] Collecting annotated-types>=0.4.0
7:18:57 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:57+0000]   Downloading annotated_types-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
7:18:58 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:58+0000] Collecting h11<0.15,>=0.13
7:18:58 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:58+0000]   Downloading h11-0.14.0-py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
7:18:58 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:48:58+0000] Installing collected packages: azure-functions, certifi, h11, httpcore, sniffio, typing-extensions, exceptiongroup, idna, anyio, httpx, distro, tqdm, pydantic-core, annotated-types, pydantic, openai
7:19:00 PM BabaOpenAi: [13:49:00+0000] Successfully installed annotated-types-0.6.0 anyio-4.3.0 azure-functions-1.18.0 certifi-2024.2.2 distro-1.9.0 exceptiongroup-1.2.0 h11-0.14.0 httpcore-1.0.4 httpx-0.27.0 idna-3.6 openai-1.12.0 pydantic-2.6.3 pydantic-core-2.16.3 sniffio-1.3.1 tqdm-4.66.2 typing-extensions-4.10.0
7:19:00 PM BabaOpenAi: WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 24.0 is available.
7:19:00 PM BabaOpenAi: You should consider upgrading via the '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.7/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
7:19:00 PM BabaOpenAi: Done in 9 sec(s).
7:19:00 PM BabaOpenAi: Preparing output...
7:19:00 PM BabaOpenAi: Copying files to destination directory '/home/site/wwwroot'...
7:19:00 PM BabaOpenAi: Done in 0 sec(s).
7:19:00 PM BabaOpenAi: Removing existing manifest file
7:19:00 PM BabaOpenAi: Creating a manifest file...
7:19:00 PM BabaOpenAi: Manifest file created.
7:19:00 PM BabaOpenAi: Done in 13 sec(s).
7:19:01 PM BabaOpenAi: Running post deployment command(s)...
7:19:01 PM BabaOpenAi: Generating summary of Oryx build
7:19:01 PM BabaOpenAi: Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
7:19:01 PM BabaOpenAi: The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
7:19:01 PM BabaOpenAi: Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
7:19:02 PM BabaOpenAi: Linux Consumption plan has a 1.5 GB memory limit on a remote build container.
7:19:02 PM BabaOpenAi: To check our service limit, please visit https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#service-limits
7:19:02 PM BabaOpenAi: Writing the artifacts to a squashfs file
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Parallel mksquashfs: Using 1 processor
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Creating 4.0 filesystem on /home/site/artifacts/functionappartifact.squashfs, block size 131072.
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: [=============================================================/] 1212/1212 100%
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Exportable Squashfs 4.0 filesystem, gzip compressed, data block size 131072
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi:  compressed data, compressed metadata, compressed fragments, compressed xattrs
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi:  duplicates are removed
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Filesystem size 4665.31 Kbytes (4.56 Mbytes)
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi:  31.68% of uncompressed filesystem size (14726.98 Kbytes)
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Inode table size 12475 bytes (12.18 Kbytes)
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi:  28.73% of uncompressed inode table size (43416 bytes)
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Directory table size 12300 bytes (12.01 Kbytes)
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi:  33.58% of uncompressed directory table size (36625 bytes)
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Number of duplicate files found 56
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Number of inodes 1350
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Number of files 1192
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Number of fragments 75
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Number of symbolic links  0
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Number of device nodes 0
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Number of fifo nodes 0
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Number of socket nodes 0
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Number of directories 158
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Number of ids (unique uids + gids) 1
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Number of uids 1
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi:  root (0)
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Number of gids 1
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi:  root (0)
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Creating placeholder blob for linux consumption function app...
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Malformed SCM_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE when uploading built content.
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Generating summary of Oryx build
***7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Deployment Failed. deployer = ms-azuretools-vscode deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
7:19:24 PM BabaOpenAi: Deployment failed.***

I am using the trial version of Azure .

Can you please help on how to resolve the rror and complete the deployment?

Was planning to deploy the python code through VSC into Azure and got the error :
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Creating placeholder blob for linux consumption function app...
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Malformed SCM_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE when uploading built content.
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Generating summary of Oryx build
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
7:19:04 PM BabaOpenAi: Deployment Failed. deployer = ms-azuretools-vscode deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
7:19:24 PM BabaOpenAi: Deployment failed.

Comment: This is a Function deployment